# ¿Como cambiar animación cursor al pasar sobre un elemento?

Tags: javascript, css, html5, script, cursor

Tengo un cursor custom en mi sitio web creado a partir de unos divs con estilos, animaciones css y código javascript. El cursor por defecto cuando pasa sobre cierto elemento tiene una propiedad por ejemplo "cursor: pointer" que hace que cambie el cursor.

El problema que tengo es que quiero que mi animación del cursor custom al posicionarse sobre un elemento como por ejemplo un link, cambie la animación a otra que yo quiera.
No se me ocurre una forma sencilla, lo único que se me ocurre es usar onmouseover sobre el elemento y llamar a una función de javascript para que me aplique los estilos que yo quiera a mi cursor custom.

Comment: Te invito a leer [ask] y [mcve]. Para poder ayudarte es necesario que muestres algún ejemplo del código que estás usando para intentar reproducir el problema. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Para eso existe `cursor: url()` [ver documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Basic_User_Interface/Using_URL_values_for_the_cursor_property) simplemente debes poner la imagen en forma de url.

```css
#happy {
    cursor: url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/9632/happy.png"), auto;
}
```

```html
<button id="happy">happy</button>
```

ejemplo tomado de [ver más](https://css-tricks.com/using-css-cursors/)

Answer (score 0):

Si estas usando jQuery puedes utilizar mouseenter y mouseleave para empezar y terminar la animación. También puedes utilizar mouseover para ejecutar la animación mientras tienes el puntero dentro del div.

```javascript
// Mouse enter/leave
$(".div-animacion").on("mouseenter", () => {
    // animation
})

$(".div-animacion").on("mouseleave", () => {
    // animation
})

// Mouse over
$(".div-animacion").on("mouseover", () => {
    // animation
})
```